# Fetching configuration in Blazor WASM PWA

Tags: blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly, appsettings

I have a PWA application written using Blazor WASM. From what I've read, an appsettings.json file should be scanned for configuration purposes, and in main I should be able to use code like this to read a value from that file:

```
var test = builder.Configuration["SettingKey"];
```

This should load test with the value in SettingKey in the json file, eg:

```
{
"SettingKey": "SomeValue"
}
```

Whenever I try this I get a null value though. Any pointer as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: It will talk to an API service and I need to specify the URL for it. At the moment I have this hard coded in the sources, but I want it to be in a config file so that the Azure DevOps pipeline that builds and deploys it can substitute different values for uat/prod, etc.

Comment: No repro. Your sample is too small to determine what went wrong.

Comment: So it worked okay for you? In that case I'll create a fresh project and try it in there. If that works then maybe wireshark might be able to give me some clues

Comment: Yes, "it just works". Like the docs say. Check the little things (spelling). Also, can you download the json with your Browser?

Comment: Migrating the project to Asp.Net core 6 (was 5) has fixed the problem, but I believe it should have worked in 5 as well. The file is accessible from the browser, yes

Answer (score 2):

Update: for appsettings.json this should "just work" already.

For some other file:

You will have to actually download that file.

First, put your extrasettings.json in the wwwroot folder.

To test it I changed the startup of a 5.0 app to this:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

    var app = builder.Build();

    var http = app.Services.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();

    using (var jsonStream = await http.GetStreamAsync("/extrasettings.json"))
    {
       // usage after the Build(), but it works
       builder.Configuration.AddJsonStream(jsonStream);
    }

    var test = builder.Configuration["SettingKey"];

    await app.RunAsync();
}
```

You can then `@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration Configuration` into your components.

Comment: Thanks Hank, that was my fallback approach, but I was wondering why the "official" approach wasn't working, as described on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Ah , you're right. I was doing way too much. It actually works  out-of-the-box. So why didn't it work for you?